# user capabilities restricted to access specific pages only in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to create a user in wordpress that will have access to only few pages in wordpress and nothing else, this user can edit , delete ,update and crreate any thing or cutomize the pages allowed to him only having no access to any other things in wordpress for that i have tried many plugins like :
UAM User Access manager
press permit Core
Role scoper
but they are not according to my needs or may be i am not using them well . any help in that will be appreciated .  i have also tried to create user through code from the backend but was not able to complete it correctly please provide any relevent help as early as possible :
i have created role through this :

```
$result = add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```

..............

```
function add_roles_on_plugin_activation() {
       add_role( 'custom_role', 'Custom Subscriber', array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
   }
   register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_roles_on_plugin_activation' );
```

but it didn't helped me much ..

Comment: Do you want a user to be  restricted from certain pages and posts in the default post type or custom post type ?

Comment: i want it in default post types ..

Comment: pages and posts have already been created i just want a user to access only the ones that i want him to access and modify only..

Answer (score 0):

I just installed and tried out this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ . It should do the trick for you. However some of it you may have to pay for if you need advanced stuff.

In this plugin, go to the Settings (AAM), then in the User Roles area, press the gear beside the role you want to edit. Then navigate to the right post or page, press gear icon again and set the permissions you desire.

If you are interested in custom code, there are ways to do it that I can provide if you prefer to not use a plugin - just let me know and I can elaborate on how to do it.

**EDIT: here's some code you could put on page.php or single.php**

Inside the loop, for admins only, do:

```
<?php 
   // First, specify only to check for permissions on certain pages/posts by ID
   if(is_page(1,2,3)||is_post(4,5,2)) {
      if(current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { ?>
        <!-- Here, all the the_title(), the_content(), etc should go -->
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } else { 
        echo 'Sorry, you don't have permission to view this page.'
      } 
   } else { ?>
  <!-- Display everything as normal -->
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to test other than admin, then try `'moderate_comments'` for Editor, `'publish_posts'` for Author, `'edit_posts'` for Contributors, and `'read'` for Subscribers (this goes into the `current_user_can()` function). See https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities.

Comment: thanks for ur help but i have alredy tried this plugin but the functionality that i need for that i have to purchase the extension i can not achieve my requirement with this plugin and yes please if u have any solution other than plugins then please explain i will appreciate it .

Comment: Added some code - take a look. It should go in page.php or post.php, inside the loop, and if the user has the right permission ability then show them the post, if not, then don't. You can further customize by adding specific IDs to check for, only, instead of doing it on all pages. (the `is_page()` part). Use `is_post()` to check for posts instead.

Comment: but this function current_user_can() is only checking the user capalibilities that whether the user has access to certain post or page or not it is not allocating capabilities to user ?

Comment: i want something that allows me to make user capable of certain things that i want him to do i dont have to chek what a user is capable of or not ..

Comment: You'll have to write a plugin like the one I linked above, then. It does allow users to access/not access specific posts, as you originally asked for.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said in your comments that you want specific posts to be disabled or restricted to be accessed by certain users which you will specify.

This has nothing to do with the user capabilities , since user capabilities either let the users see a menu in wp-admin or not ,

To hide certain records of default post type you can use this method :

1. Create a ACF multiple select box , containing lists of users (to
   which you want to hide or provide access),
2. Select those users whom you want to be blocked by accessing those page.
3. Now saving this post will also save a list of user IDs as a metadata for that page.
4. Now through hooks you can check if the current logged in users
       ID is same and if he comes to that page then you can pass a mesage.
5. Like below hook :

> this needs to be pasted in functions.php page

```
function id_WPSE_114111() {

    global $my_admin_page;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $blocked_users = get_field('blocked_users',$id);
    //try to print $blocked_users here and get only the IDs of users in an array like below
    foreach ($blocked_users as $b_key=>$b_val){
    //check how to get ID by printing the $blocked_users above
    $blocked_users[] = $b_val->ID;
    }

    //assuming that blocked users is an array of IDs
    /*
    $blocked_users = array(1,2,3,4);
    */

    //then
    if(in_array($user_id,$blocked_users)){
        echo 'Not accessible !!'
        return;
    }

}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'id_WPSE_114111' );
```

ACF field set up

1. You can download the ACF plugin from here http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
2. After installing it you will find an options in wp-admin as "Custom Fields"
3. Click on **ADD NEW** under that and create ACF group , provide it a title as User Check.
4. Click on Blue **Add Field** button  and then provide Field label, Field name, select User in Field Type, pass the intructions, see the image for more options
5. Now if user is selected in field type then you will get a list of user object when you will fetch this field at time of checking
6. Below in location tab select the post type where you want to display this field , I have selected 2 : 'Post' and 'Page' you can select more by clicking on **Add Rule Group** and adding more post types. (attached screen shot)

[image]

Comment: please will you tell where should i create this ACF multiple select box?